ERROR AL CREAR PROCEDIMIENTO EN MARIADB
Hola estoy creando el siguiente procedimiento pero me arroja error, de pronto alguien sabe en que estoy errando, gracias de antemano
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE 'ConsultaUsuariosAdministradores()'  NO SQL BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM 'vista_usuarios_administradores' ORDER BY id_admin
END//

#1064 - Existe un error en su sintaxis SQL; revise el manual que se corresponde con su versión del servidor MariaDB para averiguar la sintaxis correcta a utilizar cerca de 'DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE 'ConsultaUsuariosAdministradores()'  NO SQL BEG...' en la línea 1

que no falta un espacio ahi? y no es set delimiter?

El problema que tienes es que estas utilizando comillas donde no debes.
Aqui la forma correcta:
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ConsultaUsuariosAdministradores()  
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM vista_usuarios_administradores ORDER BY id_admin;
END //
DELIMITER ;


muchas gracias =)

El error está en el uso de comillas alrededor del nombre del procedimiento y la vista. Deben eliminarse. Usa este código correcto:
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ConsultaUsuariosAdministradores()  
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM vista_usuarios_administradores ORDER BY id_admin;
END //
DELIMITER ;


Muchas gracias :)
